# infinite requestAnimationFrame Loop in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, next.js, requestanimationframe

I am trying to recreate this app in *next.js* https://codelabs.developers.google.com/tensorflowjs-transfer-learning-teachable-machine#0

To start the data collection, I added a `onMouseDown` `MouseEvent` on the button which, triggers this code:

```js
const handleGatherDataForClass: MouseEventHandler = (e) => {
  let classNumber = parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('data-1hot'));
  console.log('inside EventHandler:', { classNumber });
  let state = gatherDataState === STOP_DATA_GATHER ? classNumber : STOP_DATA_GATHER;
  console.log({ state });
  setGatherDataState(state);
};
```

Where

- `classNumber` = positive integer
- `STOP_DATA_GATHER` = `-1`
- `gatherDataState` = `-1` (default)

Here is the original code snippet from the working app: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/tensorflowjs-transfer-learning-teachable-machine#11

After the state of the `gatherDataState` variable changes, the `useEffect` hook should run the `dataGatherLoop` function, which takes frames from the video stream and converts it into tensors:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  dataGatherLoop();
}, [gatherDataState]);


function dataGatherLoop() {
  console.log('inside Loop: ', {
    gatherDataState
  });

  if (videoPlaying && gatherDataState !== STOP_DATA_GATHER) {
    let imageFeatures = tf.tidy(function() {
      let videoFrameAsTensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(VIDEO);
      let resizedTensorFrame = tf.image.resizeBilinear(
        videoFrameAsTensor, [MOBILE_NET_INPUT_HEIGHT, MOBILE_NET_INPUT_WIDTH],
        true
      );
      let normalizedTensorFrame = resizedTensorFrame.div(255);
      return mobilenet.predict(normalizedTensorFrame.expandDims()).squeeze();
    });
    imageFeatures.print();

    setTrainData((prev) => ({
      trainX: [...prev.trainX, imageFeatures],
      trainY: [...prev.trainY, gatherDataState],
    }));

    // Intialize array index element if currently undefined.
    let newCount = [...examplesCount];
    if (examplesCount[gatherDataState] === undefined) {
      newCount[gatherDataState] = 1;
      setExamplesCount(newCount);
    } else {
      newCount[gatherDataState]++;
      setExamplesCount(newCount);
    }


    window.requestAnimationFrame(dataGatherLoop);
  }
}
```

This loop runs, as long as the `gatherDataState` variable is a positive integer (not equal to `-1`)
After the mouse button is released, an `onMouseUp` event is triggered which runs the same `handleGatherDataForClass` function as the `onMouseDown` event. This should change the state back to `-1` and therefore stop the Loop.

Problem:
Even though the state is changing to `-1` after the `onMouseUp` event is triggered, the `gatherDataState` ends up being a positive integer every time.. Therefore the loop is not stopping. (there is NO `setGatherDataState` function anywhere else in the code)

I tried:

- writing the `gatherDataLoop` function inside the `handleGatherDataForClass` event handler and passing the `gatherDataState` variable as an argument
- using a global variable for `gatherDataState` instead of a react state to save the current `gatherDataState`
- canceling the `requestAnimationFrame` loop with the `cancelAnimationFrame` function (saving the id globally and as state)

Comment: @Kaiido this line inside the handleDataGatherForClass eventhandler should first change the gatherDataState (which is -1 per default) to an positive integer: 
let state =
      gatherDataState === STOP_DATA_GATHER ? classNumber : STOP_DATA_GATHER;
when invoked again, it should change the positive integer back to -1 (STOP_DATA_GATHER)
The first line inside dataGatherLoop (after the console.log) checks if the gatherDataState is not equal to -1. If it is equal to -1 it skips the code

Comment: Wow, indentation please ;-) I was seeing that rAF call outside of the `if` block.

Comment: working on it ;). thanks for editing & commenting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure why, but

- using useRef to store the values being used inside the requestAnimationFrame loop, as well as the id for canceling the loop and
- taking the loop out of the useEffect Hook and writing it inside the ClickEventhandler

worked for me.
Here is the code:

```
 const handleGatherDataForClass: MouseEventHandler = (e) => {
    let classNumber = parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('data-1hot'));
    gatherDataStateRef.current = classNumber;
    isCollectingRef.current = !isCollectingRef.current;
    if (isCollectingRef.current) {
      collectRequestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(dataGatherLoop);
    } else {
      cancelAnimationFrame(collectRequestRef.current);
    }
  };


function dataGatherLoop() {
    console.log('inside Loop: ', gatherDataStateRef.current);

    let imageFeatures = tf.tidy(function () {
      let videoFrameAsTensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(VIDEO);
      let resizedTensorFrame = tf.image.resizeBilinear(
        videoFrameAsTensor,
        [MOBILE_NET_INPUT_HEIGHT, MOBILE_NET_INPUT_WIDTH],
        true
      );
      let normalizedTensorFrame = resizedTensorFrame.div(255);
      return mobilenet.predict(normalizedTensorFrame.expandDims()).squeeze();
    });
    imageFeatures.print();

    setTrainData((prev) => ({
      trainX: [...prev.trainX, imageFeatures],
      trainY: [...prev.trainY, gatherDataStateRef.current],
    }));

    if (examplesCountRef.current[gatherDataStateRef.current] === undefined) {
      examplesCountRef.current[gatherDataStateRef.current] = 1;
    } else {
      examplesCountRef.current[gatherDataStateRef.current] += 1;
    }

    collectRequestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(dataGatherLoop);
  }
```